# Superclass reference not able to call subclass method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a basic doubt in polymorphism in Java. I have written the code below in one file named AnimalTestDrive.java. According to me the code below should work specially the line in bold but unfortunately its not. Can you please explain why, I have given the error below:

```
class Dog extends Animal {

    public void dogMethod() {
        System.out.println("In Dog method");
    }
}

public class AnimalTestDrive {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.dogMethod();
        d.animalMethod();

        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.animalMethod();

        animal = d;
        **animal.dogMethod(); // THIS IS NOT WORKING**

    }
}
```

Comment: _According to me the code below should work_ What is your reasoning? Why should it work?

Comment: The output is coming as:
javac AnimalTestDrive.java 
AnimalTestDrive.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    animal.dogMethod();
          ^
  symbol:   method dogMethod()
  location: variable animal of type Animal
1 error

Comment: Right, so it does not work. Why do you think it should?

Comment: Because in Java a superclass reference can hold a subclass type object and then call the methods on the subclassType using the  notation as superclassRef.subClassMethod() which is done in animal.dogMethod(), but still the error

Comment: @NikhilSharma: Where do you get the "and then call the methods on the subclassType using the notation as superclassRef.subclassMethod()" part from? Where have you read that?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Kathy Sierra 'Head First Java' pg no 218 of chapter Inheritance and Polymorphism: 
Refering to lines :
But with polymorphism, the
reference and the object can
be different.
Animal myDog = new Dog();

Comment: @NikhilSharma: That doesn't say "and then you can call methods only declared in `Dog`" though does it? Yes, the compile-time type and the execution-time type can be different - but you've inferred a lot more than that.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes John, I agree I misunderstood the information. Thank you very much for clearing the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's try to look at this line the same way that the compiler would:

```
animal.dogMethod();
```

First, it needs to work out what `animal` means. That's nice and easy - it's a local variable in the current method, so it doesn't need to look far.

The compile-time type of that variable is `Animal`. The compiler doesn't care what the *value* of the variable will be at execution time - it only uses the information about the declared type.

So, that's what it uses to try to look up what `dogMethod()` means within the context of `animal`, i.e. with type `Animal`. First it looks in `Animal`, then in `java.lang.Object` (the implicit superclass of `Animal`) - but neither of those classes contains a declaration of `dogMethod`. At that point, the compiler has to give up with an error - it can't find the method. It doesn't matter that the method is available on the *execution-time* type of the object that the value that `animal` refers to. It has to bind it at compile-time, using only the information available at compile time.

The only decision made at *execution* time is which implementation of a method is used - for example, if you called `animal.toString()` and the `Dog` class had an override, e.g.

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return "I'm a dog";
}
```

then the compiler would find the `toString()` method from `java.lang.Object`, so it would know that the method call was valid - but the *implementation* in `Dog` would be used because of the execution-time type of the object.

Comment: What about run-time polymorphism and the principle that a superclass type reference in here it is animal can refer to a subclass type object, in here it is Dog. So, I think my code should work

Comment: @NikhilSharma What runtime? This failed to compile at compile time.

Comment: @NikhilSharma polymorphism would be **overriding** the `animalMethod`.

Comment: @NikhilSharma Yes, it can refer to your Dog, but the key idea here is that you're referring to it *as an Animal*, and can only perform on the Dog the methods available on Animal.

Comment: @NikhilSharma: Your code definitely *definitely* should not work. The problem isn't with the compiler or the principle that a superclass type reference can refer to a subclass type object - it's with your expectation that you can make a call to a method only declared in a subclass via an expression whose compile-time type is the superclass.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and Jon : Thank you for pointing out an obvious flaw in my expectation as correctly put by Jon that I can make a call to a method declared only in my subclass. I should have the same method dogMethod() in my animal class and then override the same in my Dog class as Sotirios has correctly pointed out. Thank you so much both of you !! Cheers !!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Superbly answered. I should have read your answer slowly. Thank you very much !!

Comment: so can we say... it is not dynamic binding, (same as saying it is not late binding), but is static binding, but with the help of virtual table, it works like it is dynamic binding?  So to make it work, it has to first be a valid usage of static binding, and then just treat it like it is dynamic binding?  I had a similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426127/in-java-why-do-have-to-typecast-a-base-class-object-to-a-subclass-object-to-cal

Comment: @太極者無極而生: I wouldn't call the last part binding, particularly... I would just separate it into compile-time overload resolution, and execution-time implementation resolution.

Comment: @JonSkeet really... I thought the polymorphic behavior is said to be done by dynamic binding, or late binding, no?  Then isn't there a static binding as in the compiler deciding what to bind or whether anything can used to bind?

Comment: @太極者無極而生: It depends on how you define "binding" - and as that can be a cause for confusion, I chose to express it without using that word at all.

Answer (score 2):

As far as Java can tell, animal is just an animal, so it can only do the things defined in your Animal class. If you want to be able to use the Dog method, and you know your animal is a Dog, you have to cast it to a Dog for the method to be visible.

In other words, the only methods and fields available for a variable are the ones defined by it's left hand side type. You can either say `((Dog)animal).dogMethod()`; to refer to animal as a Dog, or create a new variable `Dog animalAsDog = animal;` and call your method on animalAsDog.

Comment: Don't forget to cast when assigning `animal` to `animalAsDog`.