# In Java, why do we have to typecast a base class object to a subclass object to call a non-inherited method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

In the following code:

```
public class TryPet {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Pet myPet = new Pet( );
    System.out.println(myPet.speak());

    Pet myPet2 = new Cat( );
    System.out.println(myPet2.speak());

    Pet myPet3 = new Dog( );
    System.out.println(myPet3.speak());

    }
}
```

with the class definitions:

```
public class Pet {

    public String speak( ) {
    return "I'm your cuddly little pet.";
    }

}

class Cat extends Pet {
    public String speak( ) {
    return "Don't give me orders.\n" +
        "I speak only when I want to.";
    }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    public String speak( ) {
    return "woof woof!";
    }
    public String fetch( ) {
    return "Yes, master. Fetch I will.";
    }
}
```

The last line printed will be "woof woof!". We will say, (let's call this statement 1):

> `myPet3` is a `Pet object`, but more specifically, it is a `Dog object`, so that's why, when you invoke the `speak` method, it will be the behavior of a dog.

That's fine, now if we add a line to the dog speaking and make it:

```
    Pet myPet3 = new Dog( );
    System.out.println(myPet3.speak());
    System.out.println(myPet3.fetch());
```

it will have a compile error,

and statement 2 is:

> `myPet3` is a `Pet object`, but more specifically, it is a `Dog object`, so that's why, when you invoke the `speak` method, it will be the behavior of a dog.  And when you invoke the `fetch` method... oh now it is not a dog.  What????

and the rule is "you have to typecast the base class object to the subclass object if you invoke a non-inherited method."

and this line will work:

```
    System.out.println(((Dog)myPet3).fetch());
```

or if you don't use the above line, it will also work if, when you declare myPet3, you use:

```
    Dog myPet3 = new Dog( );
```

But statement 1 and statement 2 are quite contradictory.  At first we say myPet3 will exhibit the dog behavior, and statement 2 is saying, well, it has the dog behavior, but it can't fetch.

I would like to know, what reason is this?  And secondly, does it equally make sense (or make more sense) if it actually allow the fetch method to be invoked?

I think in Ruby, Smalltalk, and JavaScript, they all do not matter, and you can call `fetch`, because the variable doesn't have a type to begin with, such as in Ruby, to declare it, it is just

```
pet = Dog.new;
```

Comment: Dynamic languages are dynamic. Java is a statically typed. You can call arbitrary methods with reflection, but when using a `Pet` reference you can *only* call `Pet` methods.

Comment: When you write `Pet myPet3 = new Dog();`, you are literally telling the compiler to forget that `myPet3` is a `Dog`, and to only remember that it is a `Pet`.  You're _telling_ the compiler to forget.

Comment: @LouisWasserman and so if you say `myPet3.speak()`, then it is a runtime thing, not a compiler thing?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch when you say statically typed, is that the same as saying it is static binding? (as opposed to dynamic binding or late binding)

Comment: @太極者無極而生, correct.  The compiler knows it is a `Pet`, so it has _some_ `speak()` method; exactly which implementation to use is determined at runtime.