# Java nested enum understanding

Tags: java, enums, nested

I want to ask about nested enums. I am working with old code and i found very strange construction that i not really good understand.

I have this enum :

```
public enum DbEngines {
ORACLE("oracle", "set define on", "set define off")
, POSTGRESQL("postgresql", "--TODO set define on", "--TODO set define off");

private final String dbEngine;
private String setOn;
private String setOff;

DbEngines(String dbEngine, String setOn, String setOff) {
    this.dbEngine = dbEngine;
    this.setOn = setOn;
    this.setOff = setOff;
}

public String getSetOn() {
    return setOn;
}

public String getSetOff() {
    return setOff;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.dbEngine;
}
}
```

I added private String to this enum, that are engine specific, so it is good place for me here. The problem is, that in some places in method declaration i see something like that

```
public someMethod(Enum<DbEngines> engine, ...)
```

And it worked perfectly without methods, but now, after changing, I couldn't call public getters of this enum. But if i change to :

```
public someMethod(DbEngines engine, ...)
```

it works without any problems with all public getters. Maybe someone could explain that?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with your changes. If you try to call a type's non-overridden public methods using a superclass reference, you'll get an error.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, that's true, but maybe you could explain what happends by this casting to Eum<>

Comment: `Enum` is an abstract class. `DbEngines` is a subclass of `Enum`. Since the new methods are defined on the type `DbEngines` they are only visible using this type, not `DbEngines`'s superclass `Enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) in Java is the base class for all enumeration types. One can think of it as similar to Object class.

Just like one can hold reference of object of any class using the reference of type Object, one can refer to an enumeration type using the reference of type Enum.

```
Object o = new Integer(10);
Enum e = DBEngine.ORACLE;
```

One cannot invoke a method present in inherited class but absent in superclass using the reference of superclass.

Similar explanation over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660200/superclass-reference-not-able-to-call-subclass-method-in-java).

Comment: Note - `Enum` is a generic type. Please do not use raw types, it's a bad practice.

Comment: @RealSkeptic and Dhruvil Vaghela thanks for explanations

Comment: @RealSkeptic My bad. This was the quickest example I can come up with.